# feed dialog: picture not showing up

Tags: facebook-graph-api, parameters, dialog, feed, image

My Facebook feed dialog link correctly renders a dialog page, but the image set with the picture parameter does not show up -- just the gray line that indicates no picture.

I've changed picture files and types a few times, but the image still doesn't show up.

Here is the code:

```
$share_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=$app_id";
$share_url .= "&link=http://www.doozeez.com";
$share_url .= "&picture=http://doozeez.com/images/halloweenloot.png";
$share_url .= "&caption=to spend in the biggest rewards program in the www (whole wide world)";
$share_url .= "&name=doozeez ... get zeez for what you dooz";
$share_url .= "&description=grab your invitation to join me at the front of the line for doozeez launch";
$share_url .= "&redirect_uri=http://www.doozeez.com/";
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $share_url . "'</script>");
```

I've done it with and without a urlencode() for the picture url, and that doesn't make a difference. I've also run it through the Facebook debugger linter.

Is there something we need to change in our php.ini file? Our image files seem to be unavailable to the Facebook platform. Yet, they display on the public web just fine.

Here is the rendered url: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=192590464145496&link=http://www.doozeez.com/&picture=http://doozeez.com/images/halloweenloot.png&caption=to%20spend%20in%20the%20biggest%20rewards%20program%20in%20the%20www%20(whole%20wide%20world)&name=doozeez%20...%20get%20zeez%20for%20what%20you%20dooz&description=grab%20your%20invitation%20to%20join%20me%20at%20the%20front%20of%20the%20line%20for%20doozeez%20launch&redirect_uri=http://www.doozeez.com/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounters this issue, make note that Facebook requires your image to an have extension (even if you already use the proper headers). This is true even if your image works in the lint tool without an extension like `.png` or `.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a .png image

I change the image format to .gif and it resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gets a 404 Error when accessing your images please check your .htaccess file.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdoozeez.com%2Fimages%2Fhalloweenloot.png

Greetings,
Frederick

Comment: Frederick, which setting in .htaccess should I change to allow Facebook and other servers to access my images?

Comment: Please show me your htaccess to see if there is any Problem with it.

Comment: Here are the .htaccess contents: Action application/x-pair-sphp /fcgi-bin/php5.cgi AddType application/x-pair-sphp .php Options -Indexes

Not much there. I wonder if there is some setting we need to change in our php.ini file to allow other servers to access our image files?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if it is because this website has no SSL Certificate (even though it is not a canvas app and should not need one). Because, the URL keeps reverting to "https://" while the image files are "http://" links. Will get an SSL Cert and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since october 1st 2011 every pagetab needs https too.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

But my image doesn't show up in the feed dialog, althought it's shown up in the fb debug console... :S

Comment: I just changed from https to http and now it works. But we got an valid SSL cert for this domain. *shrug* but it doesn't matter - http works fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative problem I experienced was that I had already shared the image to facebook and at that time had authentication enabled for the site, which I then disabled. However when I tried to share with facebook it had seemed to cache the previous issue and that was causing the problem. Changing the file name or trying again later would resolve it. In my case I deleted the image and made a new one (they were dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved this was changing the protocol from https to http **and** changing the image format from png to jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one still is looking for an answer. I found out that my domain had Hotlink Protection on, that's why it was stopping all images from directly being referenced. So in order for Facebook to reference my images directly, I had to turn off Hotlink Protection. Another alternative (better one, I guess) is only to add facebook.com as an exception to be able to hotlink your images.

My web host was Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

for me: I had lowercase `.jpg` in the url string, but the actual image file was uppercase `.JPG'